# Combining text as blocks

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Let's start two blocks of text, for example

```
a = """CAC
ABA
CAC"""
b = """AAA
BBB
CCC"""
```

If we add these two strings, we will end up with

```
>>> print(a+b)
CAC
ABA
CACAAA
BBB
CCC
>>>
```

I was wondering if there is a fast way to add large blocks of text so that they print side by side, like so:

```
>>> print(a+b)
CACAAA
ABABBB
CACCCC
>>>
```

I know that one can do

```
>>> print('\n'.join(list(a.split('\n')[x]+b.split('\n')[x] for x in range(3))))
CACAAA
ABABBB
CACCCC
>>>
```

but is there a faster method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'\n'.join(map(str.__add__, a.split('\n'), b.split('\n')))
```

You can also replace `.split('\n')`, with `.splitlines()`, not sure if that will make it faster.

Note that in your own code, the `list(...)` is not needed, `join` accepts any iterable.

Comment: In what way is this faster than the given method?

Comment: @UnsignedByte `map` with built-in functions is usually faster than manual python loops. You'll have to test with `timeit` to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is that you split the lines of `a` and `b` on each and every iteration.  You only need to split the lines once, at the beginning.

```
>>> pairs = zip(a.splitlines(), b.splitlines())
>>> '\n'.join([''.join(p) for p in pairs])
'CACAAA\nABABBB\nCACCCC'
```